# Setting Null values for Case when in proc sql

Tags: sql, sas

I have a dataset

```
Period  Brand   ID
  Jan    A      X1
  Jan    A      K1
  Jan    B      CT2
  Feb    C      X2
  Feb    A      P4
```

I would like to do a distinct count of ID for each brand under each period.  I tried using CASE WHEN in proc sql to count the distinct number in each period, but I am unsure of what to set for the else portion, since I am guessing SAS will also count the else part as a distinct item also.  My code is as below:

```
 proc sql;

    create table items as
    select period,
    count(distinct case when brand="A" then ID else "." end) as Count_A,
    count(distinct case when brand="B" then ID else "." end) as Count_B,
    count(distinct case when brand="C" then ID else "." end) as Count_C
from Data
group by period;
quit;
```

I do understand that I am able to use sub query to construct each count variable also, but the code is likely to get very long and tedious.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your query should work so long as you use `NULL` for the `ELSE` condition.  You can achieve this by simply not listing any `ELSE` condition, in which case `NULL` would be used by default.

```
select
    period,
    count(distinct case when brand = "A" then ID end) as Count_A,
    count(distinct case when brand = "B" then ID end) as Count_B,
    count(distinct case when brand = "C" then ID end) as Count_C
from Data
group by period
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:-

```
/*Creating Dataset*/
data a;
input Period $3. Brand$1. Id$3.@;
datalines;
JanAX1
JanAK1
JanBCT2
FebCX2
FebAP4
JanA
FebB
JanAX1
FebCX2
;
run;

/*Counting distinct by giving another condition for Id with brand should do 
  the job for you*/
 proc sql;

    create table items as
    select period,
    count(distinct case when (brand="A" and ID not=" ") then ID end) as 
    Count_A,
    count(distinct case when (brand="B" and ID not=" ") then ID end) as 
    Count_B,
    count(distinct case when (brand="C" and ID not=" ") then ID end) as 
    Count_C
from a
group by period;
quit;
```

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hard code each column, then add Brand to the `group by` statement, then transpose the result.  This is a useful method if there lots of different brands.

```
data have;
input Period $ Brand $ ID $;
datalines;
Jan    A      X1
Jan    A      K1
Jan    B      CT2
Feb    C      X2
Feb    A      P4    
;
run;

proc sql;
create table temp
as select
    period,
    brand,
    count(distinct id) as count
from have
group by period, brand;
quit;

proc transpose data=temp out=items (drop=_NAME_) prefix=Count_;
by period;
id brand;
var count;
run;
```